# DjangoRestFramework ModelSerializer ignores required extra data

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have some ModelSerializer like:

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    x = serializers.IntegerField(required=True, write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = (...some MyModel fields..., 'x')
```

x is not a MyModel field.

Problem: when I send request without x in form_data, drf doesn't raise "required" error.
Expected: 400 response with message of missed 'x' is required.

I am able to write it by myself, but it looks like undefined behavior or I missed something in docs.

Comment: It should be `serializers.IntegerField` instead of `serializer.`

Comment: since x is not model field becasue at the end the model fields gets connected with model,

Answer (score 0):

Solved - the problem was in the `partial=True` flag.